# Best GWT blogs?

Tags: gwt, blogs

Aside from the official [GWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) blog, which GWT blogs do you read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://turbomanage.wordpress.com
- http://borglin.net/gwt-project

Comment: The GWT best practices blog is really good!

Answer (score 8):

The most frequently updated:

- http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/

Other:

- http://gwt-unofficial.blogspot.com/
- http://www.gwtapps.com/
- http://gwtblog.mynumnum.com/

You can also find answers on [GWT Discussion Group](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit?pli=1) or on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt).

Answer (score 2):

- [Lomardi Development Blog](http://development.lombardi.com/) has excellent posts covering some rare, but very useful topics.
- [Ray Cromwell's blog](http://timepedia.blogspot.com/) is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

I follow these sites:

- http://gwtblog.mynumnum.com
- http://www.gwtnow.com
- http://www.gwtsite.com
- http://stuffthathappens.com/blog
- http://roberthanson.blogspot.com
- http://timepedia.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

My bookmark contains following sites:

- http://turbomanage.wordpress.com
- http://timepedia.blogspot.com
- http://www.gdevelop.com/
- http://raibledesigns.com
- http://googletesting.blogspot.com
- http://lemnik.wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this one here as well:

http://webcentersuite.blogspot.com

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer from *years* ago...

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self promotion:   [www.gwtsushi.info](http://www.gwtsushi.info)

Answer (score 0):

I just started my own :
http://micouz.blogspot.fr/